# Connect to SSO based Github account from AWS Sagemaker Notebook instance

Tags: github, single-sign-on, amazon-sagemaker

We are trying to host our code in the Github account which uses GitHub organizations and has an SSO-based auth login mechanism through PingID IDP. We want to develop code in the Sagemaker studio notebooks and version control our code in Github. We are looking for easy ways to establish connections within these platforms. Please share inputs to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Studio or Classic Notebook Instances (The title mentions notebook instances but your question mentions studio)?

Classic Notebook Instances:

SageMaker notebook instances give you the flexibility to control networking. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/understanding-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-networking-configurations-and-advanced-routing-options/

If you repo is private you may have to set up the notebook instance with either:

1. Customer attached VPC with direct internet access (2 network interfaces)
2. Customer attached VPC without direct internet access.

Studio:

Similar options for Studio: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-notebooks-and-internet-access.html

I suspect as long as your networking checks out you should be able to connect to your git repo as you would do, say on EC2.